# C# monitors (from a Java developer POV)

Tags: c#, java, concurrency, monitor

I'm working on the port of a C#/directx game client to Java, so that I can learn some C# (as I am completely profane on it) and in the meanwhile improve my knowledge on a java opengl engine.

When I encounter something like the following:

```
Monitor.Enter(preloadDictionary);
try {
     foreach (PreloadEntry entry in preloadDictionary.Values) {
         if (entry.loaded) continue;
         return entry;
     }
} finally {
     Monitor.Exit(preloadDictionary);
}
```

can i assume it is like the following?

```
syncronized(preloadDictionary) {
     [...]
}
```

And in the case of:

```
Monitor.Enter(worldServerMap);
try {
     worldServerMap[rv.WorldName] = entry;
     Monitor.PulseAll(worldServerMap);
} finally {
     Monitor.Exit(worldServerMap);
}
```

is the additional `PulseAll()` like a `notifyAll()` to wake up all thread waiting on the resource? (but i could not find any place in the code where `Monitor.Wait()` is called).

Comment: Yes and yes. In C#, it is also more typical to use "lock (preloadDictionary)", which is a shorthand for the Monitor.Enter(...); try...finally { Monitor.Exit(...);} block you described.

Comment: @Alan: this should be an answer.

Comment: @JBNizet: well, I'm not quite sure about the missing Monitor.Wait() part, so this doesn't constitute an answer by my standards, but still wanted to give a quick feedback to the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lock(x) is itentical to Monitor.Enter then Monitor.Exit in the finally. It is a langauge shortcut.

If you ask me, it is one of the weaker parts of the C# language - simply because while it was nice while there was a MINOTIR, these days there are various versions of monitors (slim, spinlock etc.) and lock only supports one of them. It is convenient, but I am not sure it is wise ;)

> is the additional PulseAll() like a notifyAll() to wake up all thread
>   waiting on the resource? (but i could not find any place in the code
>   where Monitor.Wait() is called).

The PulseAll makes little sense unless you have an explicit wait, possibly from other threads not wanting to Enter. Enter waits if it can not get a lock, so Exit is enough to make normal synchronization.

I would start looking for a Wait or something else - PulseAll on a MOnitor makes only sense if you have threads waiting WITHOUT trying to Enter at this stage. It could lead to a bad design issue that basically has them waiting then get pulsed then try to enter, it could be part of a non blocking design of some dsort - hard to say, but it is unusual. Unless you can find a Wait somewhere in your code, I would likely try killing the PulseAll and see what happens.